# How many automorphisms a countable field has?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{B}$ a countable algebraically closed field (car=0) of infinite transcendence degree. How many automorphisms $\mathbb{B}$ has? Are they $2^\omega$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of the field $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots)$, where the $x_i$ are "indeterminates."  Any of the $2^\omega$ one to one onto maps from $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ to itself induces an automorphism of $A(x_1,x_2,\dots)$. There can be no more than $2^\omega$ automorphisms, for there are only $2^\omega$ **functions** from our field to itself.

Answer (score 1):

As $\mathbb B$ is countable, there are certainly not more than $|\mathbb B^{\mathbb B}|=2^{\aleph_0}$ automorphims.
On the other hand, there are countably many separable irreducible polynomials over the prime field, each giving rise to a finite choice, thus $2^{\aleph_0}$ automorphisms.